# OpenERP Unique Constraint

Tags: python, odoo

I have a table  in OpenERP/PostgreSQL with the following columns: `name` and `description`.

I added the following validation for unique name:

```
_sql_constraints = [('unique_name', 'unique(name)', 'A record with the same name already exists.')]
```

It works fine but it is case sensitive. Currently, it accepts values such as "Mickey", "MICKEY" and "mickey":

```
Wrong Way:
--------------------------
| name   | description   |
--------------------------
| mickey | not a mouse   |
--------------------------
| MICKEY | not a mouse   |
--------------------------
| Mickey | not a mouse   |
--------------------------
```

Is there a way to revise the validation code so that it will not allow users to add several values such  as "Mickey", "MICKEY" and "mickey"? How can I make the unique key validation case insensitive?

```
Right Way:
--------------------------------
| name         | description   |
--------------------------------
| mickey       | not a mouse   |
--------------------------------
| mickey mouse | is a mouse    |
--------------------------------
| donald       | is a duck     |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `case insensitive constraints` check out [HERE](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2005-09/msg00842.php)
else you can always use Openerp Constraints instead of SQL .

for openerp Constraints

check the example

```
def _check_unique_insesitive(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    sr_ids = self.search(cr, 1 ,[], context=context)
    lst = [
            x.FIELD.lower() for x in self.browse(cr, uid, sr_ids, context=context)
            if x.FIELD and x.id not in ids
          ]
    for self_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if self_obj.FILD and self_obj.FILD.lower() in  lst:
            return False
    return True

_constraints = [(_check_unique_insesitive, 'Error: UNIQUE MSG', ['FIELD'])]
```

Comment: Hi Ruchir! thanks for the prompt response. Can you give me an example how I can implement the desired validation using OpenERP Constraints?

Comment: List out all Data for Specific field in one list. Convert it in either Lower or upper Case, Then check for the New Value with in operator , and return the opposite of result .

Comment: It worked. Thanks Ruchir!
I just modified the list to exclude the last entry

Comment: you mean the current object's data ? then last entry will not work always if you have different sorting order, Please change this
lst = [x.FIELD.lower() for x in self.browse(cr, uid, sr_ids, context=context) if x.FIELD]
to 
lst = [x.FIELD.lower() for x in self.browse(cr, uid, sr_ids, context=context) if x.FIELD and if x.id not in ids]

Comment: Yes Ruchir, the data being entered/inputted in the form. I did this: lst = [x.name.lower() for x in self.browse(cr, uid, sr_ids, context=context) if x.name and x.id !=last_rec_id] Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

This way without read all data from database:

```
def _check_unique_insesitive(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    for self_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if self_obj.name and self.search_count(cr, uid, [('name', '=ilike', self_obj.name), ('id', '!=', self_obj.id)], context=context) != 0:
            return False

    return True

_constraints = [(_check_unique_insesitive, _('The name must be unique!'), ['name'])]
```

Answer (score -1):

using constrains in Odoo 8.0 or above in a simpler way.
get all records of the model and check the desired field value with lower() and excluding the self record.

```
@api.constrains('code')
def _check_duplicate_code(self):
    codes = self.search([])
        for c in codes:
            if self.code.lower() == c.code.lower() and self.id != c.id:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError("Error: code must be unique")
```

Comment: Answers should contain description of what code does not just a block of code. Answers from questions that are more than a year old with other answers especially, should include reasons as to why this answer is relevant due to any changes in the language or differences between the other posted answers.