# OpenERP 7 _constraints

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
class deduction_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.deduction.registration"
    _description = "Deduction Registration"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Deduction Name', size=256, required=True),
    }
    _sql_constraints = [('deduction_registration_name_unique', 'unique(name)', 'Deduction name already exists')]

deduction_registration()
```

I created above sql constraints for my model.but its still allow duplicate records without case sensitive.

like **EPF** and **epf** allowed
how to add constraint for that.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenERP Unique Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263507/openerp-unique-constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class deduction_registration(osv.osv):

    def _check_unique_insesitive(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        sr_ids = self.search(cr, 1 , [], context=context)
        lst = [x.name.lower() for x in self.browse(cr, uid, sr_ids, context=context) if x.name and x.id not in ids]
        for self_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if self_obj.name and self_obj.name.lower() in  lst:
                return False
            return True

    _name = "bpl.deduction.registration"
    _description = "Deduction Registration"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Deduction Name', size=256, required=True),
    }
    _sql_constraints = [('deduction_registration_name_unique', 'unique(name)', 'Deduction name already exists')]
    _constraints = [(_check_unique_insesitive, 'Deduction name already exists', ['name'])]

deduction_registration()
```

with this code i have done my job   :-)